# Issue with taskAffinity and excludeFromRecents on Android 10

Tags: android, android-activity, android-notifications, android-task, taskaffinity

I have an application which is sometimes displaying notifications to users.
When pressing a notification, a "Dispatch" Activity is triggered which calls `startActivities` with some intents leading to proper activity depending on the notification payload.
Here is how it is declared in Manifest according to https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation#ExtendedNotification

```
            android:name=".DispatchActivity"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" />
```

When I press a notification, `DispatchActivity` is launched with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` and launches a new activity with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` before it immediately calls finish(). If my application was already launched, the new activity (let's call it the `second Activity`) is launched on top of previous already launched activity so when you press Recents button, you can see my app only once.

[image]

[image]

This is actually the behaviour I want. The thing is, when I run the same code on Android 10 and press Recents button, I can see two instances of my app (well two tasks I guess)  :

[image]

If I press Recent button again to restore the second Activity, it just goes away and I only have the initial Activity. As if SecondActivity inherited from `excludeFromRecents` behaviour where this is not the case on other Android versions (I even tested on Android 11 preview and it's working as expected).

I tried removing `taskAffinity=""` for `DispatchActivity` in Manifest so it has same affinity as other Activities in the application, but I then have issues when receiving a notification with my app not launched where activities launched from DispatchActivity are going away like initially on Android 10 because of `excludeFromRecents` tag.

I'm running out of idea right now so if you have any solution or maybe have already met the problem I'm open for suggestions.

Thanks !

Here is the sample code if needed : https://github.com/LoicJ/MultiTaskBugSample.git

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `android:noHistory="true"` add this line to your activity in the manifest file it will provide your expected behavior.

Your final code may look like:

```
<activity
        android:name=".DispatchActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:taskAffinity="" />
```

Comment: Tried with `android:noHistory="true"` but it does not change anything. I still can see two occurences of my app in recent apps panel which is not the case on other Android versions.

Comment: android OS  level?

Comment: Device is on Android 10.  Project has targetSdk = 29 and compileSdkVersion = 29.

Comment: Have you tried android:autoRemoveFromRecents="true" and  android:excludeFromRecents="true"